# c++ array of pointer to string and append() method

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I want to have array of pointers to strings.

```
std::string *part [n];
```

I also have object witch has method that return string,

let's name it:

```
object1.getText();
```

when I want to get part of the string to array's element it's not a problem:

```
std::string h = object1.getText().substr(0,5) 
array[0] = &h;
```

but how can I append some text to existing element?

something I've tried:

```
std::string hh = object1.getText().substr(6) 
array[0].append(&hh);
```

didn't work.

Comment: Future bug: `array[0] = &object1.getText().substr(0,5);` the `string` returned by `substr` does not last long enough for a pointer to it to be meaningful.

Comment: `std::string::append` has no overload that accepts a pointer to a `string`. `array[0].append(...)` should be `array[0]->append(...)` because `array [0]` is a pointer. I recommend going over the section on pointer syntax in your text book again and working through some of the examples.

Comment: okey, my fault it's clear now, thank @user4581301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank to  @user4581301 , the solution is

```
std::string *part [n];

std::string h = object1.getText().substr(0,5) 
array[0] = &h;

std::string hh = object1.getText().substr(6);
array[0]->append(hh);
```